# How to test if ldap server is up or not?

Tags: directory, ldap, openldap

How i can test if ldap server is working or not .One way to use to Apache directory Studio client any other way if we can check if ldap server is running or not ?

Please remember i cannot login server machine where ldap installed i have to test it from a client machine.Please let me know what all mechanism or client we can use test ldap connection ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test whether any resource is available is simply to try to use it in the normal course of your application, and cope with the errors as they arise.

Otherwise you're trying to predict the future, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring tools such as Zabbix, InterMapper,SCOM etc can provide status health.

Answer (score 0):

You could try watching port 389 on the server. That port can be and is often changed. So you will need to get it from the admin of the ldap server.